# Find asymptotic boundary of recursion with sum

Tags: summation, asymptotics, recursion

Given $T(n) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{\log n} T(\lfloor  \frac {n}{k^i} \rfloor)
\right) + n $ where $k \ge 3$, how do I prove that $T(n) = \theta(n) $?

I tried replacing $n$ with $2^m$ when $m = \log n$ bug it doesn't seem to help.

In general, how do I calculate the handle these kind of questions? I saw this: [How to tackle a recurrence that contains the sum of all previous elements?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/667929/how-to-tackle-a-recurrence-that-contains-the-sum-of-all-previous-elements/668033#668033) but I'm struggling to implement it in the mentioned above case...